# Any idea why a python comclient PDF (from word document created by python docx ) does not tag table headers correctly?

Tags: pdf, com, python-docx

i have to create numerous (Americans with Disabilities Act) ADA accessibity compliant PDFs of long tables every year - a single table spans many pages.

The data for the tables are on text files.
I first use python Docx to create word documents of the tables that are properly spaced, formatted, and contain metadata such as title, author, etc.

So far so good. If I do a preliminary check by opening that Word doc and using the Acrobat extension built into Word to create a PDF, the table header is accurately tagged when I run the Adobe Accessibility Checker.

But i dont want to manually create each PDF, so I then use python Comclient to create  PDFs from the Word documents. Everything looks good except I get an error when I run the Accessibility checker saying the table headers failed.

If I look at the PDF tags, the first row of the table  has a  tag with the word Path repeated over and over PathPathPathPathPathPathPathPathPathPathPathPathPath. After the Span tag, the table headers are correctly tagged as .
[image: PDF tags bad]

That Span tag is not there on the PDFs created from the same document using the Acrobat extension built into Word, so I assume it is the reason for the Header failure when i create the PDF using the comclient python code.

[image: PDF tags good]

Any ideas on what might be causing this Span tag and/or how to stop it?

Possibly relevant docx code used to make headers:

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Cm, Pt, Inches
from docx.oxml import OxmlElement
from docx.oxml.shared import OxmlElement
from docx.oxml.ns import qn
import docx
import os
import sys
import comtypes.client
from docx.enum.text import WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH
from docx.enum.table import WD_ALIGN_VERTICAL
   
--function from github raphaelvalentin , much appreciated!
     def set_repeat_table_header(row):
            """ set repeat table row on every new page
            """
            tr = row._tr
            trPr = tr.get_or_add_trPr()
            tblHeader = OxmlElement('w:tblHeader')
            tblHeader.set(qn('w:val'), "true")
            trPr.append(tblHeader)
            return row

--function from github AlbinoShadow, much appreciated: 
    def prevent_document_break(document):#keeps table rows from splitting in half over a page break
        """https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/245#event-621236139
           Globally prevent table cells from splitting across pages.
        """
        tags = document.element.xpath('//w:tr')
        rows = len(tags)
        for row in range(0, rows):
            tag = tags[row]  # Specify which <w:r> tag you want
            child = OxmlElement('w:cantSplit')  # Create arbitrary tag
            tag.append(child)  # Append in the new tag

doc = docx.Document()
cp = doc.core_properties
cp.author  = name #name defined previously
cp.title = title #title defined previously
table = doc.add_table(rows= row_ttl, cols= col_ttl)
table.autofit = False 
table.allow_autofit = False
table.style='Light Grid Accent 1'
set_repeat_table_header(table.rows[0])
```

Possibly relevant comclient code used to make pdfs

```
           pdf_name = file[:-3]+'pdf'
            prevent_document_break(doc)
            doc.save(ada_pdfs_folder+fldr+'/word_docs/' + file_name)
            wdFormatPDF = 17
            in_file = ada_pdfs_folder+fldr+'/word_docs/' + file_name
            out_file =ada_pdfs_folder+fldr+'/' + pdf_name
            word = comtypes.client.CreateObject('Word.Application')
            doc2 = word.Documents.Open(in_file)
            doc2.SaveAs(out_file, FileFormat=wdFormatPDF)
            doc2.Close()
            word.Quit()
```

Thanks for any thoughts or suggestions
-Kimberly

Comment: Those could be repeated Table Headers with the same xpath that are on different pages.

Comment: Use `print(table._tbl.xml)` to inspect the XML of a table that works and one that doesn't and see if you can identify the difference that might account for this behavior.